# FindNextFileA returns 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, console-application

There is a function to recursively find all files in a folder (stored in **logPath** folder name has **'\'** at the end). It is used in **64** bit console application (compiled in MSVC 2008) and runs on Win7 **64** bit OS.

When I run the application like "program.exe folder_to_find" it works well.

When I run the application like "program.exe folder_to_find >> result.txt" it fails with error 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) returned FindNextFileA (even without recursive call on big folders). E.g. it could find first 150 files in the folder instead of existing 240 ones.

```
void FindFiles(const std::string &logPath, FileList& fileList)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA fd;
    HANDLE f = FindFirstFileA((logPath + "*").c_str(), &fd);

    if (f == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("No files found at %s - %d\n", logPath.c_str(), GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    FileList dirList;
    do
    {
        if (strcmp(fd.cFileName, ".") == 0)
            continue;
        if (strcmp(fd.cFileName, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        std::string path = logPath + fd.cFileName;
        printf("Processing %s\n", path.c_str());
        if (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            dirList.push_back(path);
        else
            fileList.push_back(path);
    }
    while (FindNextFileA(f, &fd) != 0);

    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    if (err != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        printf("Unexpected error in FindNextFileA(%s): %d\n", logPath.c_str(), err);
        fflush(stdout);
        abort();
    }

    FindClose(f);

    //for(FileList::const_iterator it = dirList.begin(); it != dirList.end(); ++it)
    //  FindFiles(*it, fileList);
}
```

Comment: Is the result file being created in the directory you are searching (or in a sub-directory of the directory you are searching)? If so maybe having a file open (and being changed) while the directories are being searched is causing a problem. You are probably going to have to do some experimenting to find out more about the conditions that cause this problem.

Comment: No, result file is being created outside the target directory. No files are opened, at least by the program.

Comment: printf?! Why not use `cout`? Then you could avoid those yacky `c_str()` calls. You must also call `GetLastError()` immediately after the associated API call fails. You don't do that in the code in the Q.

Comment: `printf` is just a bad habit, sorry. `GetLastError`, as I see, is called immediatly after `FindNextFileA` call.

Comment: That one is fine, but the one after FindFirstFileA is not. Surely `logPath.c_str()` won't be a problem, but it's a good habit to get into being very precise about when you call `GetLastError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `boost::thread t` and I store its handle by `HANDLE h = t.native_handle()`

There was a call `CloseHandle(h)` to close it later.

I forgot, then `boost::~thread()` destructor also closes its handle.

After I dupllicate thread handle 
`HANDLE h = NULL;` 
`::DuplicateHandle(..., t.native_handle(), &h, ...)`  
before closing - the problem dissappeared...

Comment: Why are you closing the thread handle manually at all? Why not let `boost::thread` handle that for you?

Comment: This piece of code is a part of test for another application, where was the `CloseHandle` to close processes handles, and the threads were to imitate a behavior of this processes.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say why `FindFirstFileA()` would return that particular error code when console redirection is used (you did not show how you are outputting the results to the console), but there are some minor errors in your code (most notably, you are not doing adequate error handling on `FindFirstFileA()`, and not appending `\` to the end of directory paths with calling `FindFiles()` recursively).

Try this instead:

```
void FindFiles(const std::string &logPath, FileList& fileList)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA fd;
    DWORD err;

    std::string sLogPath(logPath);
    if (sLogPath.length() > 0)
    {
        if (sLogPath[sLogPath.length()-1] != '\\')
            sLogPath += '\\';
    }

    HANDLE f = FindFirstFileA((sLogPath + "*").c_str(), &fd);
    if (f == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        if (err != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            printf("Unexpected error in FindFirstFileA(%s): %d\n", sLogPath.c_str(), err);
            fflush(stdout);
            abort();
        }

        printf("No files found at %s\n", sLogPath.c_str());
        return;
    }

    FileList dirList;
    do
    {
        if (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if ((strcmp(fd.cFileName, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(fd.cFileName, "..") != 0))
            {
                std::string path = sLogPath + fd.cFileName;
                printf("Processing dir %s\n", sLogPath.c_str());
                dirList.push_back(path);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::string path = sLogPath + fd.cFileName;
            printf("Processing file %s\n", path.c_str());
            fileList.push_back(path);
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFileA(f, &fd));

    err = GetLastError();
    FindClose(f);

    if (err != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        printf("Unexpected error in FindNextFileA(%s): %d\n", sLogPath.c_str(), err);
        fflush(stdout);
        abort();
    }

    //for(FileList::const_iterator it = dirList.begin(); it != dirList.end(); ++it)
    //  FindFiles(*it, fileList);
}
```

Comment: This code causes the same error after 122nd subdir — **Unexpected error in FindNextFileA(1\): 6** when console redirection is used

Comment: Look carefully at that error message. It says that `logPath` was `"1"`, which is not a valid path. That should be your first clue that something is wrong. `FindNextFileA()` is complaining that `f` is not a valid handle. So something outside of the code shown here is corrupting memory and both of your variables are victims of that corruption. What is `FileList` declared as? Does it grow dynamically or does it have a limit of how many entries it can hold?

Comment: I've changed in your code `logPath + "*"` to `logPath + "\\*"` to run. `FileList` declared as `typedef std::vector<std::string> FileList;`. I rely on STL. :) There was no outside code — I've commented all but this code and `main`, where I pass `argv[1]` to `FindFiles`.

Comment: If you change the filter to use `+"\\*"` then you have to remove `+"\\"` when calling `FindFiles()` in the recursive loop, and you have to make sure NOT to include `'\'` at the end of the `argv[1]` value. I suggest having `FindFiles()` assign `logPath` to a local variable, append `"\\"` to the end of it if missing, and then use that variable everywhere instead of using `logPath` directly. But that still does not explain why `logPath` is `"1"` and `f` is invalid when the failure occurs. That still suggests memory corruption.